# How to structure content types in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, entity-relationship, drupal-content-types

I want to build a homebrew beer app and am at a loss for how to deal with structuring this type of content.

I have a Content Type called Recipe. Each recipe is comprised of Grain Type, Grain Amount, Hop Type, Hop Amount, Yeast Type and Yeast Amount. There are multiple Grains and Hops that can be used. For each: Grain, Hop and Yeast; there is data associated that I would like to display. I am getting hung up on if I should use Entity Relationship or Taxonomy Terms or both?

I have attached how I would like the pages to be laid out if this helps:
http://www.theidealform.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Recipe-Fields.png

[image]

After I get this structured correctly I am going to have to try to figure out how to have a selection screen that the user can hit "save" on and save the selection (of Grain, Hops or Yeast) back to their Recipe.

http://www.theidealform.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Selection-Screen.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This would be a use for Entity Reference, not Taxonomy Terms. You'll probably also want to use Entity Reference Prepopulate so that when you create the Grain/Hop/Yeast, it already knows what Recipe node to reference it to, as opposed to having to set it manually via a select. Entity Prepopulate Reference: https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate

As for your second question, if you want to direct the user somewhere after submitting a form, you can use the destination parameter to define where they should go. In your case, if you have a link on the page to create a new grain, you could modify the link so it's "/node/add/grain?destination=link_to_your_recipe_here", replacing link_to_your_recipe_here with the actual link of the recipe you'd like to go back to. When the user clicks on the link, they're taken to the Grain node creation form. Because of the destination parameter, when the save the form, they're then taken back to the recipe.

This page has more on using destination parameter: http://www.tecnomeme.it/appunti_web/how-add-destination-url-drupal